# Silverlight navigation application, how to add a page that's not part of the "navigation"

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight navigation application, and I thought it would be no problem to add a page that's not part of the "navigation" app. What I would like to do is move the user from the application to a new "fullscreen" page where there's only a text covering the page saying, thanks for using....... click here to login again, and that will take the user back to my already implemented login page.

The question is how can I implement a page that's not part of the user, then I guess all I need to do is navigationservice.navigate(..)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you add the new page as a "Silverlight User Control" instead of a "Silverlight Page" from the Visual Studio Silverlight templates you will get the results you are looking for.